# How to change root (first) bone in armature

Tags: armature, bones, parent

This seems like a common question but I can't find anyone talking about it.

I made a very complex armature, spent a couple days on it, only to realize the root bone (I call handle) is in the wrong place. It is in the middle of the spine, I want the "butt" bone to be the new root bone so that I can bend the spine normally. Messing with parenting in edit mode doesn't seem to work or is too complicated for me.

Here is the .blend file:

[image]

And a screenshot:

[image]

How do I fix this ?

Comment: It will be impossible to answer this without the blend file I'm afraid. Could you please upload it to http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ ? From a screenshot no one can really judge which bone is the parent of which, etc. The rig itself should do, you don't have to implement a mesh.

Comment: It might be in the armature tab of the properties panel and then perhaps a field to set the name? But I don't have access to Blender right now to confirm.

Comment: Ok, I added the .blend file. The problem is when I bend the spine both halves of the body bend around the "handle". I really wouldn't have realized until after I made the mistake.

Comment: Seems like a common problem.....I guess not ?

Answer (score 1):

Just “add bone” from menu to add a new bone that isn’t the child of anything. Then Ctrl+P make it the parent of the existing root and choose “keep offset.” The root is “the bone that has no parent.”

Answer (score 0):

that doesn't change the root there is a point that looks like a compass with a circle in the middle and 4 lines around it pointing up down left and right that is the root question is how do we relocate it to another place without moving our character or any bones but to make it the new point which all else moves around, I have the same problem
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can evaluate if its worth erasing the root and his child bones, until you reach the bone which you want to be the root. This work for me in a horse armature in which the root bone was the last tail bone and I wanted an spine bone as the root.